# media queries for smartphone portrait, landscape and desktop?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to set different media queries for smartphone orientation and desktop, i want to target portrait and landscape. I am aware of all the other stack links such has:

[Media query to target most of smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224913/media-query-to-target-most-of-smartphone)
[3 media queries for iphone portrait, landscape and ipad portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910255/3-media-queries-for-iphone-portrait-landscape-and-ipad-portrait)

But I am still having issues, my landscape one isn't working, this is the code I am using:

```
Desktop css first
   -- css for desk --

Portrait:

   @media only screen 
     and (min-device-width: 320px) 
     and (max-device-width: 479px) {

}

Landscape:

   @media only screen 
     and (min-device-width: 480px) 
     and (max-device-width: 640px) {

}
```

The landscape code is like not even getting considered

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try adding

```
orientation : landscape

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) 
                   and (max-device-width: 640px) 
                   and (orientation: landscape) {

//enter code here
}
```

See [**this site**](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/) or **[this snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/67341/)** for reference.

Comment: adding "and (orientation: landscape)" will have an effect on the desktop too tho

Comment: but the width declarations will filter out desktop

Comment: This media query doesn't target any latest phones who have widths more than 480px in landscape

Comment: If you're targeting landscape, is the width now the width in landscape? Or still the width in portrait?

Answer (score 10):

It's better to tackle the height than the width since the width has a large amplitude of sizes while 575.98px for mobile is, at least for now, a range that covers a LOT of devices.

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 575.98px) and (orientation: landscape) {
//enter code here
}
```

Comment: This is what worked for me in the end. The height of the viewport is the real issue I was trying to tackle.

Comment: If you're targeting landscape, is the width now the width in landscape? Or still the width in portrait?